# I want a simple authentication with bearer token and rest api which should be stored in local storage and be refresh in given time in REACT

Tags: reactjs, authentication, rect

I want a simple authentication with bearer token and rest API which should be stored in local storage and be refreshed in the given time in REACt.
as I know react is a library and tends to do simple work that concerns on Effective UI and Ux. What about HTTPS request stuff and also authentication . I guess Axios should be the fine approach for HTTP request but using third-party library is sick n RWACt especially if you are a beginner who doesn't have a much understanding of promises than react makes you have a nightmare. Any Solution will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use axios for this purpose. you can use it like this :

```
axios.post('/login', data)
    .then(response => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
    });
```

Also you can use axios interceptors for this purpose. It will run for every request call. for validating and setting headers to requests like this:

```
const config = {url:'https://...',timeout:10000}

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.url,
  timeout: config.timeout
});
instance.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    const token =  localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  error => Promise.reject(error)
);
```

Comment: Sir ? how can we use this data further?